# Force close when setting id to an include layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, forceclose

Currently I'm working on an Android Project consisting of `Toolbar` instead of the regular `ActionBar`.
I have defined the `Toolbar` in a separate `layout` file named as `tool_bar.xml`, and then I include the `ToolBar` in every layout where I need it.

My Activity's Layout file is named as `acceptor.xml`.
My Java file name is `Acceptor.java`.

My Question is that, whenever I `include` the `tool_bar.xml` in `acceptor.xml` and provide the included layout an `id`, it gives me a `force close error`, and it goes smooth when I remove that id attribute.

Please help!

**All the needed resources like `Logcat`, `xml` files, `Java` files are posted below :**

***`tool_bar.xml`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

***`acceptor.xml`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--Attribute android:id causes the force close-->
    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:id="@+id/action_accept"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAcceptorHeader2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Below is the List of Donors you need!"
            android:textColor="#8A0707"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sort_divider2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvAcceptorHeader2"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sort_divider2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="3dp"></ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sort_divider2"
            android:layout_margin="10sp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvListEmpty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="No Filters Applied. Please apply the filters below!"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/handle_sliding_closed" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAcceptorHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Please apply the filters below to show a list of Donors!"
                android:textColor="#8A0707"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/header_divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvAcceptorHeader"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header_divider"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinBGSort"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:entries="@array/bg_types_sort"
                    android:prompt="@string/bg_prompt"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/acCitySort"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:hint="Your City here"
                    android:singleLine="true"></AutoCompleteTextView>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etZipcodeSort"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:hint="Your ZIP CODE here"
                    android:singleLine="true"></EditText>

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/cbLocation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:text="Use my Location" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bFilter"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                    android:text="Filter" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/sort_divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:background="#000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***`LogCat`***

```
    01-04 21:04:26.348  22744-22744/com.developit.bloodgency E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.developit.bloodgency, PID: 22744
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.developit.bloodgency/com.developit.bloodgency.AcceptorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.developit.bloodgency.AcceptorActivity.onCreate(AcceptorActivity.java:107)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 21:15:00.718  24442-24442/com.developit.bloodgency E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.developit.bloodgency, PID: 24442
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.developit.bloodgency/com.developit.bloodgency.AcceptorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.developit.bloodgency.AcceptorActivity.onCreate(AcceptorActivity.java:107)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***`Acceptor.java`***

```
//package
//import statements

public class AcceptorActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener,
        OnDrawerCloseListener, OnDrawerOpenListener {


    private static final String DONOR_LIST_URL = "http://bloodgency.developitltd.com/donor_list.php";
    // JSON IDS:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_DONORS = "donors";
    private static final String TAG_DONOR_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACT = "contact_number";
    private static final String TAG_BG = "blood_group";
    private static final String TAG_COUNTRY = "country";
    private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";
    private static final String TAG_CITY = "city";

    private static final String TAG_ZIP = "zip_code";
    // php read comments script
    private static final String TAG_AREA = "area";
    Button handle;
    SlidingDrawer sd;
    TextView tvListEmpty, tvAcceptorHeader;
    CheckBox cbLocation;
    Button bFilter;
    EditText etZipcodeSort;
    AutoCompleteTextView acCitySort;
    String blood_group_selected;
    String zipCode, zipCode_location, city_location, cityName;
    GPSTracker gps;
    Spinner spinBGSort;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSortCity;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // it's important to note that the message is both in the parent branch of
    // our JSON tree that displays a "Donor Available" or a "No Donor Available"
    // message,
    // and there is also a message for each individual post, listed under the
    // "posts"
    // category, that displays what the user typed as their message.
    // An array of all of our comments
    private JSONArray mDonors = null;
    // manages all of our comments in a list.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDonorList;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acceptor_screen);
        Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        //Line 107
        actionBar.setTitle("Get Blood Donors");
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(actionBar);

        spinBGSort = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinBGSort);
        spinBGSort.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        bFilter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFilter);
        bFilter.setOnClickListener(this);
        cbLocation = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbLocation);
        cbLocation.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        etZipcodeSort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etZipcodeSort);
        acCitySort = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acCitySort);
        tvListEmpty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvListEmpty);
        tvAcceptorHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAcceptorHeader);
        handle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);
        sd = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
        sd.open();
        handle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.handle_sliding_open);
        sd.setOnDrawerCloseListener(this);
        sd.setOnDrawerOpenListener(this);

        String[] city_list_india = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.indian_cities);
        adapterSortCity = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city_list_india);
        acCitySort.setAdapter(adapterSortCity);
        acCitySort.setThreshold(0);

        // create class object
        gps = new GPSTracker(AcceptorActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // \n is for new line

            /*
             * Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
             * "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude,
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */

            // lat,lng, your current location

            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                        longitude, 1);

                zipCode_location = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                city_location = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

            } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            cbLocation.setEnabled(false);
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings

        }
        if (cbLocation.isChecked()) {
            if (!gps.canGetLocation())
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        /*
         * new LoadDonorList().execute("ALL Blood Groups", zipCode_location,
         * city_location);
         */

    }

    /**
     * ... /** Retrieves recent post data from the server.
     */
    public void updateJSONdata(String bg, String zipCode, String cityName) {

        // Instantiate the arraylist to contain all the JSON data.
        // we are going to use a bunch of key-value pairs, referring
        // to the json element name, and the content, for example,
        // message it the tag, and "I'm awesome" as the content..

        mDonorList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Bro, it's time to power up the J parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Feed the beast our comments url, and it spits us
        // back a JSON object. Boo-yeah Jerome.
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(DONOR_LIST_URL);

        // when parsing JSON stuff, we should probably
        // try to catch any exceptions:
        try {

            mDonors = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DONORS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mDonors.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mDonors.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String contact_number = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT);
                String blood_group = c.getString(TAG_BG);
                String country = c.getString(TAG_COUNTRY);
                String state = c.getString(TAG_STATE);
                String city = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
                String zip_code = c.getString(TAG_ZIP);
                String area = c.getString(TAG_AREA);

                if (bg.equals(null) || blood_group.equals(bg)
                        || bg.equals("ALL Blood Groups")) {
                    if (zip_code.equals(zipCode) || zipCode.equals("")) {

                        if (city.equalsIgnoreCase(cityName)
                                || cityName.equals("")) {
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                            map.put(TAG_CONTACT, contact_number);
                            map.put(TAG_BG, blood_group);
                            map.put(TAG_COUNTRY, country);
                            map.put(TAG_STATE, state);
                            map.put(TAG_CITY, city);
                            map.put(TAG_ZIP, zip_code);
                            map.put(TAG_AREA, area);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            mDonorList.add(map);

                            // annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with
                            // our
                            // array
                            // list
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {
        // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to
        // do
        // that, we need to create a ListAdapter. This SimpleAdapter,
        // will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList,
        // use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
        // and place the appropriate info from the list to the
        // correct GUI id. Order is important here.
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mDonorList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_BG,
                TAG_CONTACT, TAG_COUNTRY, TAG_STATE, TAG_CITY, TAG_ZIP,
                TAG_AREA}, new int[]{R.id.tvListName,
                R.id.tvListEmail, R.id.tvListBG, R.id.tvListContact,
                R.id.tvListCountry, R.id.tvListState, R.id.tvListCity,
                R.id.tvListZipCode, R.id.tvListArea});

        // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we
        // could do something. However, we will choose
        // to do nothing...
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);
        if (lv.getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {

            lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
            tvListEmpty
                    .setText("No Donors to display with this Filter. Please apply another filter!");
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    // This method is triggered if an item is click within our
                    // list. For our example we won't be using this, but
                    // it is useful to know in real life applications.

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                               long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bFilter:
                try {
                    findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    blood_group_selected = spinBGSort.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String zipCode = etZipcodeSort.getText().toString();
                    String cityName = acCitySort.getText().toString();

                    if (!cbLocation.isChecked()) {
                        if (zipCode.equals("") && cityName.equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(this,
                                    "Please enter atleast one of CITY or ZIP CODE",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else
                            new LoadDonorList().execute(blood_group_selected,
                                    zipCode, cityName);
                    } else {
                        zipCode = zipCode_location;
                        cityName = city_location;
                        new LoadDonorList().execute(blood_group_selected, zipCode,
                                cityName);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "An error Occurred while fetching the Donor List",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (cbLocation.isChecked()) {

            etZipcodeSort.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            acCitySort.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {
            etZipcodeSort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            acCitySort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        handle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.handle_sliding_open);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        handle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.handle_sliding_closed);
    }

    public class LoadDonorList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AcceptorActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Loading Donor List");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // we will develop this method in version 2
            updateJSONdata(arg0[0], arg0[1], arg0[2]);
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            updateList();

            sd.close();

        }

    }
}
```

I hope this is sufficient to get what my problem is.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException            at com.developit.bloodgency.AcceptorActivity.onCreate(AcceptorActivity.java:107)` . Thats your clue. Check line 107 for null references

Comment: Tried but no luck, Posting the java file too

Comment: So which line is 107?

Comment: Its `actionBar.setTitle("Get Blood Donors");` as commented in the code above.

Comment: So `actionBar` is null.  Try copying and pasting it into acceptor.xml (as a test).  Does it work then?

Comment: Thanks, but what to paste in acceptor.xml, actionBar is a java reference variable here, ??

Comment: I think you need to understand the basics better.  It should be obvious - `Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);`

Comment: Lol, I know dude, its already include there :-) , I thought you are saying to include java variable..

Comment: Will try doing the same and let you know. @Simon

Comment: Remove `android:id="@+id/action_accept"` from the `<include>`, since you are not using it anywhere. The Toolbar ID should be the one defined in `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` . Maybe this line is overriding the original ID.